# Make list with data retrieve from mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this problem I have this 3 entities, `Operator`, `Programs` and `News`. The `Programs` and `News` tables have a column `Operator_ID` with determinate thats that is from one `Operator`.

Then at the main of the web page I want to make a list of the `Operator` and his `News` and `Program` in a single list. I have this code html but I need to merge with the php..

```
<div id="news-block">
    <h3 id="news-title">
        <a href="">NAME OPERATOR</a></h3>
    <ul id="news-content">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="">Program</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="">New</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problems come when the operator doesn't have news but programs yes.. or not programs but news yes..

---

EDIT:

```
<?php
if($programas!=null)
{
  $nombre = null;
  foreach ($programas as $programa) {
    if($programa->ingreso!= date('Y-m-d',time()-(24*60*60))){
      if ($programa->operador!= $nombre) {
        $nombre = $programa->operador;
        echo  "<div id='news-block'>";
        echo "<h3 id='news-title'>".anchor('locheco/Ver_Operador/'.$programa->user_id, $programa->nombre)."</h3>";
        echo '<ul id="news-content">';
      }
      echo "<li>".anchor('programa/Ver_Programa/'.$programa->id, $programa->titulo,'target="_blank"')."</li>";
      foreach ($promociones as $pr) {
        if($pr->operador==$programa->operador  && $programa->ingreso!=date('Y-m-d',time()-(24*60*60)))
        {
          echo "<li>".anchor('programa/Ver_Programa/'.$pr->id, $pr->titulo,'target="_blank"')."</li>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

So if don't have programas and have news don't show it..

Comment: You haven't shown the php you need tomerge with and you haven't explained precisely what "problems come when the operator dont have news but programs". Personally I don't see any problems with that situation.

Comment: I retrieve the news and programs in two arrays from the db, the problem is this look at the edition.

Comment: Search left joins, sounds like you have 3 tables joined but if there isn't both it returns nothing. That is what a left join is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay on clarification of the question the answer is different. Retrieve news and programs into separate variables.

Controller:

```
$data['news']=array();
$data['news']=$this->modelname->getNews($operatorId);
$data['programs']=array();
$data['programs']=$this->modelname->getPrograms($operatorId);
```

View:

```
if(!empty($news))
{
    //display news code in here
}
if(!empty($programs))
{
    //display programs code in here
}
```

Comment: Yes I think in that but then to merge with the html.. how I difference  if he has or not program or news..

Comment: sec, I'll edit the answer. grabbing it as a join isn't what you want, grab it as two separate things.

Comment: Yes that its good, but what if have the two (News and Programs) that I need to show in the same block.. understand?

Comment: I don't see the problem? If they aren't empty they'll show. It's just where you place the if blocks. If they're meant to go together then put them together in the HTML.

Comment: But if have news and programs have to show together and not programs and news separate

Comment: Are news and programs linked together in some way other than by operator?

Comment: Then to be honest I'm not getting the problem.